# Merging 2 datasets in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, inner-join, merging-data

I have 2 diffferent datasets and I want to merge these 2 datasets based on column "country" with the common country names and dropping the ones different. I have done it with inner merge, but the dataset is not as I want to have.

> inner_merged = pd.merge(TFC_DATA,CO2_DATA,how="inner",on="country")

TFC_DATA (in the orginal dataset there exits a column called year but I've dropped it):

| Country | TFP |

| Angola | 0.8633379340171814 |

| Angola | 0.9345720410346984 |

| Angola | 1.0301895141601562 |

| Angola | 1.0850582122802734 |

```
.
.
.
```

CO2_DATA:
| Country | year | GDP | co2

| Afghanistan | 2005 | 25397688320.0 | 1

| Afghanistan | 2006 | 28704401408.0 | 2

| Afghanistan | 2007 | 34507530240.0 | 2

| Afghanistan | 2008 | 1.0850582122802734 | 3

| Afghanistan | 2009 | 1.040212631225586  | 1

.
.
.

What I want is

Output
|Country|Year|gdp|co2|TFP
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|0.8633379340171814
Angola|2006|66748907520.0|19.006|0.9345720410346984
Angola|2007|87085293568.0|19.006|1.0301895141601562
.
.
.

What I have instead

Output
Country|Year|gdp|co2|Year|TFP
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2005|0.8633379340171814
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2006|0.9345720410346984
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2007|1.0301895141601562
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2008|1.0850582122802734
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2009|1.040212631225586
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2010|1.0594196319580078
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2011|1.036203384399414
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2012|1.076979637145996
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2013|1.0862818956375122
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2014|1.096832513809204
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2015|1.0682281255722046
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2016|1.0160540342330933
Angola|2005|51967275008.0|19.006|2017|1.0

I expected the datas of the countrys' merge in one dataset but it duplicates itself until the second one data is over then the second one does the same

Comment: Its really hard to see the data please try to format the data but at the face of it seems that `TFC_DATA` has **one row per country**, while `CO2_DATA` has **one row per year per country**. To get the output you want, you can first **reshape** `TFC_DATA` so that it has one row per year per country, and then merge it with `CO2_DATA`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pd.merge()` function performs an inner join by default that means it only includes rows that have matching values in the specified columns.

Use a different join type one option is to use a left outer join, which will include all rows from the left dataset `(TFC_DATA)` and only the matching rows from the right dataset `(CO2_DATA)`.

Specify a left outer join using the `how="left"` parameter in the `pd.merge()` function.

`merged_data = pd.merge(TFC_DATA, CO2_DATA, how="left", on="country")`

After @abokey's comment
**EDIT**

First, create a new column in the TFC_DATA dataset with the year value

`TFC_DATA["year"] = TFC_DATA.index.year`

Group the TFC_DATA dataset by "country" and "year", and compute the mean TFP value for each group

`TFC_DATA_agg = TFC_DATA.groupby(["country", "year"]).mean()`

Reset the index to make "country" and "year" columns in the resulting dataset

`TFC_DATA_agg = TFC_DATA_agg.reset_index()`

Perform the inner merge, using "country" and "year" as the merge keys

`merged_data = pd.merge(CO2_DATA, TFC_DATA_agg, how="inner", on=["country", "year"])`

Comment: It still does not change the output

Comment: Updated my answer @Pelin Kasap

Comment: @Sachin, you can't run `TFC_DATA["year"] = CO2_DATA["year"]` just like that because this assumes so many things. And also, there is no need to add this column since the OP said that he dropped it at the first time.

Comment: I receive "KeyError: 'year'"

Answer (score 0):

> TFC_DATA (in the orginal dataset there exits **a column** called year but
> **I've dropped it**):

Well, based on your expected output, you should not drop the column `Year` from the dataframe `TFC_DATA`. Only then, you can use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=pandas%20merge#pandas.merge) (*as shown below*). Because otherwise, you'll have duplicated values.

```
pd.merge(CO2_DATA, TFC_DATA, left_on=["country", "year"], right_on=["country", "Year"])
```

OR :

```
pd.merge(CO2_DATA, TFC_DATA.rename(columns={"Year": "year"}), on=["country", "year"])
```

Comment: Actually, this gives an error. KeyError: 'Year'. I tried to write with small letters as well as capital letter; country, Country, year, Year. Each time gives an error with different key word

Comment: Can you `print(TFC_DATA.columns)` and  `print(CO2_DATA.columns)` share the outputs ?

Comment: Index(['country', 'Year',
       'Total factor productivity index (using national accounts) (2017=1)'],
      dtype='object')     

  ;
                            Index(['country', 'year', 'gdp', 'co2'], dtype='object')